# Try catch in PHP, Can I go this way?

Tags: php, try-catch

I writing a script which has to read content from URL all the time. Instead of ...

```
// block 1
Try{
    if(!someAction1){
        throw new exception(someException1);
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    //exception handling code
}

// block 2
Try{
    if(!someAction2){
        throw new exception(someException2);
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    //exception handling code
}

// block 3
Try{
    if(!someAction3){
        throw new exception(someException3);
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    //exception handling code
}
```

Can I change in to this ...

```
Try{
    someFunction1()
}catch(Exception $e){
    //exception handling code
}

public someFunction1(){
    if(!someAction1){
        throw new Exception(someException1);
    }

    if(!someAction2){
        throw new Exception(someException2);
    }

    someFunction2()

}

public someFunction2(){
    if(!someAction3){
        throw new Exception(someException3);
    }
}
```

The reasone I want to do this because there are a lot of try-catch block to create. But all of them only to prevent the script from stopping itself (I'm running it with Crontab). The exception handling code is simple, write the error log file (Same for every try-catch block)

Comment: Why not try it yourself you'll learn better that way ;)

Comment: If it is syntactically correct, yes you can do that. Beware that try/catch won't ensnare fatal errors, curl timeouts, and exceeded script execution times (which your question use case sounds like).

Comment: @locrizak & @mario I will try to night. Unfortunately, this script search content from hundreds of website, a lot of category each. Last time it was running for 7 hours before stopped (unfinished) which I don't know why because there is no error in the log file. Maybe it stopped because of another reason (Timeout, MySQL problem, Server Restriction bla bla bla)

Comment: Most of the content from sites is fine. But sometimes, I end up with unexpected error like the content contains backslash , single/double quote (which I solve it already). But for this time, If I modify the script. If I go for test run again after code modification. I have to wait until an unexpected error happen again. Because of no error, try-catch block won't have to do its job and I will never know that this modification is OK or not.

Comment: PHP isn't designed to run scripts for 7 hours. Try/catch won't help you. Make a workpool, and repeatedly run the script to process parts of whatever it is it is doing.

Comment: @Thaninrat If you know your script is going to be running for a while, you might want to implement your own logging system.  Here is a link to get your started -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341154/php-logging-framework

Comment: @mario I would also recommend that, or if it's the bottle-neck is cpu/memory related (I think your case it's network), then you could try porting your script to c++ or java to make it run faster.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that.

Just go and try it out yourself.

Comment: I split the two sentences up onto two lines. Hope you're well now.

Comment: Try the delete link instead. This isn't IRC or a bulletin board. If you are unwilling to provide an answer in proportion to the question, regardless how simple, then why don't you just leave it? -- And again: there is a comment feature for that.

Comment: @mario: As far as I understood, the question Thaninrat asked was: "Can I change X into Y?". In my eyes, "Yes" is an acceptable answer to a yes/no question.

Comment: Well, you didn't understand the context of the question then. It's about a different topic. And your "answer" is not helpful to OP.